# Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `name` is marked as required in `SignIn`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs

So I´m developing a chat application. I´m also trying to use an older chat application I worked on some time ago. But now when editing my code according to React v16, prop-types instead of react PropTypes, I am stumpling on several issues. So I´ve got most of the application working, but I there is a new syntax that I´m missing. Here is the file I´m stuck on.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Button, Input } from 'reactstrap';
import * as actions from '../actions/actions';

class SignIn extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.setState = {
      username: this.props.welcomePage || '',
      password: ''
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.username.length) {
      this.refs.passwordInput;
    } else {
      this.refs.usernameInput;
    }
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    if (event.target.name === 'username') {
      this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
    }
    if (event.target.name === 'password') {
      this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
    }
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    if (this.state.username.length < 1) {
      this.refs.usernameInput;
    }
    if (this.state.username.length > 0 && this.state.password.length < 1) {
      this.refs.passwordInput;
    }
    if (this.state.username.length > 0 && this.state.password.length > 0) {
      var userObj = {
        username: this.state.username,
        password: this.state.password
      };
      dispatch(actions.signIn(userObj))
      this.setState({ username: '', password: ''});
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <header style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', background: '#000000', color: '#FFFFFF', flexGrow: '0', order: '0'}}>
          Sign In to Chat
        </header>
        <main style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <Input
              label="Username"
              ref="usernameInput"
              type="text"
              name="username"
              placeholder="Enter username"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
            <Input
              label="Password"
              ref="passwordInput"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Enter password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
            <Button
              className="btn success"
              style={{width: '100%', height: '4rem', marginTop: '2rem'}} name="submitButton"
              type="submit" >
                <p style={{color: 'white', margin: '0', padding: '0', fontSize: '1.5em'}} >Sign In</p>
            </Button>
          </form>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SignIn.propTypes = {
  welcomePage: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};



function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
      welcomePage: state.welcomePage,
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn)
```

Comment: There is no name on your `SignIn.propTypes` ... are you sure you got the updated code?

Comment: There where no "name:" in my previous chat applications propTypes. But yes, I thought about that earlier, didn´t do any difference though. Or maybe I´m not using it correctly..

Comment: There's no way this error would be triggered without `name: PropTypes.string.isRequired` in your `SignIn.propTypes`.

Comment: Are you saying I need a name PropType? Because I´ve tried with and without. It still sends error about:
value={this.state.username}
and
Failed prop type: The prop `name` is marked as required in `SignIn`, but its value is `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry. Just saw that I did a moronic spello in my constructor. How silly